# Convert timestamp to under certain condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have timestamp column and for the start time if my time is greater than 5:30Pm I would like to consider the time as 5:00PM and I need to subtract the converted minutes from start date and enddate.

```
SELECT [starttime], [endtime],
       case when  FORMAT([starttime],'HH:mm') >'17:30' then  17.00
       end as newstarttime,
       FORMAT([endtime],'HH:mm') as newendtime
FROM Table1
```

I tried to convert the timestamp into 24hour format but not sure about the next steps.

```
Starttime                     Endtime
2019-08-13 17:40:33:000       2019-08-13 19:00:00:000
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.  Explain what to do with times such as 5:15 pm.  What happens to 12:05 am?  Also SQL Server has a `timestamp` datatype but it is nothing like what you are describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using SQL Server, and I think you want:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when convert(time, starttime) >= '17:30:00'
             then dateadd(hour, 17, convert(datetime, convert(date, starttime)))
             else starttime
        end) as new_starttime
from table1 t1;
```

You can also express the date add logic as:

```
convert(datetime, convert(date, starttime)) + '17:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Yes,  I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am getting the following error using the code you just shared.                          
                                                                                                                                          
 "The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date".

Comment: @Pihu . . . That always gets me.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have timestamp field and for the start time if my time is greater than 5:30Pm I would like to consider the time as 5:00PM

To do this, its easier to work with dates than doing character conversion.  See the below query:

```
SELECT [starttime], [endtime]     
    , case    
    when FORMAT([starttime],'2020-01-01 HH:mm:00') > '2020-01-01 17:30:00' then '17:00'     
    else FORMAT([starttime],'HH:mm')    
    end as newsttime
    , FORMAT([endtime],'HH:mm') as newendtime    
FROM Table1;
```

What do you mean by:

> I need to subtract the converted minutes from start date and enddate.